# Error plotting in 2D

Tags: error-propagation

I have some data: along Y axis: 5.86*10^(-8),2.56*10^(-8),3.21*10^(-8) with error 0.58, 0.25 and 0.32 respectively.
along X axis: there are some range corresponding each value of Y axis such as: 
0.1-2, 2-5, 5-8 respectively. Now I want to plot error bar with these values in my following plotting. By doing programming I have obtained the following 2D plotting. In the same plotting if I want to show error bar also then what command I will use?[image]

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: code means I don't understand

Comment: Plot[{s1,s2},{s,0,20},PlotStyle->{Red,Blue},Frame->True,FrameStyle->Directive[Black],Filling->{1->{{2},Green}}]. This is only for the above plotting, not for the error data.